# Intriguing pdfgrep situation

Tags: pdf, grep

I'm having a strange problem with pdfgrep that I can't explain. I have a 400 kB OCR-scanned pdf-file. In this file I have placed 4 markers (Mark_01, Mark_02, Mark_03 and Mark_04).

When I open the file in Evince or Adobe Reader and search I will find a match for all these 4 markers.

However, when using this command:`pdfgrep -n "Mark_01" file.pdf`

....it returns nothing.

Though if I edit the command to `pdfgrep -n "Mark_0" file.pdf`

....it will find all 4 matches.

It has the same behaviour no matter which marker I search for.

Any ideas?

/Paul

Comment: Upload your pdf file somewhere and add a link in your question.

Comment: Can't do that I'm afraid since it contains somewhat sensitive information. I did a rescan though changing the markers to Markword-01, Markword-02, Markword-03 and Markword-04. It gives the same result. No single match can be found but when searching for "Markword-0" all 4 matches are found. I seems something in pdfgrep can't handle "-" or "_" followed by double integers.

Comment: I found the reason to this behaviour, though not a solution. It seems as if a match is found as a line final (i.e. "Markword_01"), then pdfgrep can't see a match. When I added a random character after the marker (i.e. "Markword_01A") then the marker is found. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Here is a link with a file: http://www.filedropper.com/02_4  The marker "Markword-01" will not be found by <pdfgrep -n "Markword-01" 02.pdf>, though it will be found by <pdfgrep -n "Markword-0" 02.pdf>. Is this a normal behaviour of pdfgrep and if so why?

Comment: It looks like a bug in pdfgrep. pdftext shows "Markword-01".

Comment: Yeah, and that's a real pity since pdfgrep can show page number where the match is found, but pdftext can not.

Comment: If you look for page number, try `pdftohtml -noframes 02.pdf -stdout | grep Markword-01`. Output: `<A name=1></a>Markword-01<br>`. 1 is page number.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is indeed a [bug in poppler](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91644), the rendering library that pdfgrep uses.

The [fix](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/commit/?id=e5511b58e732f921c65e366fb4d221371b95d905) was committed on August 27 and will be in the upcoming 0.36.0 release.